# Get files with a name containing a date value less than or equal to a given input date

Tags: linux, shell, grep

One of my folders contains files in the following format:

```
3_20150412104422154033.txt
3_2015041211022775012.txt
3_20150412160410171639.txt
3_20150412160815638933.txt
3_20150413161046573097.txt
3_20150413161818852312.txt
3_20150413163054600311.txt
3_20150413163514489159.txt
3_2015041321292659391.txt
3_20150414124528747462.txt
3_20150414125110440425.txt
3_20150414134437706174.txt
3_20150415085045179056.txt
3_20150415100637970281.txt
3_20150415101749513872.txt
```

I want to retrieve those files having a date value less than or equal to my input date value.

For example, if I give "3_20150414" which is (3_YYYYMMDD), I want the output to be the file names

```
3_20150412104422154033.txt
3_2015041211022775012.txt
3_20150412160410171639.txt
3_20150412160815638933.txt
3_20150413161046573097.txt
3_20150413161818852312.txt
3_20150413163054600311.txt
3_20150413163514489159.txt
3_2015041321292659391.txt
3_20150414124528747462.txt
3_20150414125110440425.txt
3_20150414134437706174.txt
```

I can list the files by issuing a command like this:

```
ls -l | grep '20150413\|20150414' |awk '{print $NF}'
```

But I am struggling to find a **`<=`** match.

Comment: +1 for using the YYYYMMDD format, which allows date strings to be treated as numbers (and to compare correctly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `awk` and its string comparison operator.

```
ls | awk '$0 < "3_20150415"'
```

In a variable:

```
max=3_20150414 export max
ls | LC_ALL=C awk '$0 <= ENVIRON["max"] "z"'
```

concatenating with "z" here makes sure that the comparison is a string comparison, and allows any time on that day since in the `C` locale, digits sort before `z`.

In `zsh`, you can also do:

```
print -rC1 -- *.txt(e['[[ $REPLY < ${max}z ]]'])
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` doesn’t have a ≤ operator *per se*,
but there’s a kludgy way to fake it.  You want all dates between the year 0
(or the year 1; whichever the first year was) through 20150414. 
(I’ll assume that BC dates are off the table.) 
Break this range into subranges that can be matched by regular expressions:

- Year 0 through 1999 — all years begin with 0 or 1, so grep for `[01]`.
  (All regular expressions will be assumed to be anchored
  at the beginning of the line, right after the “3_”.)
- Year 2000 through 2009 — regex `200`.
- Year 2010 through 2014 — regex `201[0-4]`.
- Year 2015, month 1 through month 3 — `20150[1-3]`.
- Year 2015, month 4, day 1 through 9 — `2014040`
- Year 2015, month 4, day 10 through 14 — `2014041[0-4]`

and then put them all together:

```
grep -E '3_([01]|200|201[0-4]|20150[1-3]|2015040|2015041[0-4])'
```

`ls -l`, of course, gives you lots of information about the files
(mode, owner, mod time, etc.) which you don’t need,
so you use `awk '{print $NF}'` to strip it out and leave only the filename. 
This is inefficient and error prone
(it breaks if a filename has a space or tab in it). 
Parsing the output from `ls` is never a great idea,
but you can make it a little safer by making it a little simpler:
just don’t get the information you don’t want or need,
and then you don’t need to discard it.

```
ls | grep -E '3_([01]|200|201[0-4]|20150[1-3]|2015040|2015041[0-4])'
```

should be good enough.

But building that six-part regular expression is tedious and error prone,
and difficult (although not impossible) to script.  Here’s a cleaner way:

```
ls | awk 'substr($1, 3, 8) <= 20150414'
```

This extracts the eight characters starting with the 3rd position
(i.e., after the “3_”) and compares it to 20150414
as two eight-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution using your example:

```
ls -l | grep '3_2015' | awk -v d='3_20150414' '{ s = substr($NF, 1, 10); if (length(s) == 10 && s <= d) print $NF; }'
```

I changed a little your grep pattern and pass searched value as argument to `awk` where we just compare strings to output desired things.
Also there is a lot of articles why you should not [parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) so I change it a little with find:

```
find . -type f -name '*3_2015*' -printf "%f\n" | awk -v d='3_20150414' '{ s = substr($NF, 1, 10); if (length(s) == 10 && s <= d) print $NF; }'
```